# two SVG on same page

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to render two svg objects on a same page but only first one is rendered, the second page has text "this is a second page text" which is not showing.

http://jsfiddle.net/myTv4/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"   xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 936 629" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(304.89 84)">
<text font-family="arial" font-size="20" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-83.89 19)">
<tspan x="0" y="-13" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">click todsfsdfs edit!</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(319.68 239)">
<text font-family="arial" font-size="20" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-81.68 19)">
<tspan x="0" y="-13" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">this is blocked text</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"   xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(255.46 254)">
<text font-family="arial" font-size="20" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #18bd18; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-104.46 19)">
<tspan x="0" y="-13" fill="#18bd18">this is second page text</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

and its showing question mark character when server render it, I don't know why its showing this character. when I save as the page its fine

http://screencast.com/t/zLQPhb3vB

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This part has pushed your text away from the page

```
<g transform=           "translate(255.46 254)"                >
<text font-family="arial" font-size="20" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #18bd18; opacity: 1;" 
transform=              "translate(-104.46 19)"                >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinodh/myTv4/1/

ERROR is in positioning (svg transform translate part)...
"translate(-104.46 19)" pushes the line in a minus X Axis direction 104.46px

Recommend you to use a vector based editor for creating SVG's such as
Adobe Illustrator (paid),
Corel Draw (paid),
[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) (free),
[SVG edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html) (free)

Regarding the question marks... !
It should be a encoding error from the server...
Try seeing what encoding your server is sending! It should be changed to UTF-8.